# matrix-by-matrix derivative in case of x^Tx

Tags: matrix-calculus

I've read somewhere on this forum that if we have three matrices $A,X,B$ that are $m\times n$, $n\times k$ and $k\times l$ respectively, that
$$\frac{\partial (AXB)}{\partial X}=B^T \otimes A$$
Now if we apply this to product $x^Tx$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^T$ (so $x$ is $n\times 1$ matrix), we have that
$$\frac{\partial (x^tx)}{\partial x}=E(1)^T\otimes x^T=x^T,$$
where $E(1)$ is the identity matrix of dimension 1.

But, $\frac{\partial (x^tx)}{\partial x}$ should be equal to $2x^T$? What is going on?

Comment: $B^T$ and $A$ are assumed to be constants. So $x^Tx$ is not of the form you described in the beginning.

Comment: $f:=x^Tx = \| x \|_2^2$. Then, the gradient of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2 x$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (or $2x^T$ depending on the layout). You can do the search on the gradient of L2 norm.